# Need to get list of taxonomy terms which have published posts

Tags: wordpress, taxonomy

I need to display a list of taxonomy terms, but only those which have posts with status "published".  ie:  if a term has no publicly available posts, then I don't want it displayed.  For example, I have a taxonomy called regions:

- California
- New York
- Italy
- Australia
- France
- etc

I only want to display the regions which have posts with status "published".
My code so far is:

```
$regions = get_terms("region");
foreach ( $regions as $region) {
    echo "<li>" . $region->name . " : ". $region->slug ."</li>";
}
```

Comment: By default empty terms are hidden and not displayed. So the manner you"ve used the code is correct

Comment: Do you mean that if there is a taxonomy term that only has posts with status "draft" or "private", that term will not come up when I use get_terms() ?

Comment: I just tested this -- for a taxonomy term with 3 matching posts, I changed all 3 posts to status "private", and `get_terms()` still brought up that term.  I tried also changing published status to "draft" and also to "pending review", but that term kept on coming up.  So my original question still remains -- how can I bring up only the taxonomy terms will published posts??